# WSUS trying to download all updates again

Tags: wsus

The server hosting WSUS had a catastrophic failure and we have had to rebuild the system drives.  Luckily the DB and content store for WSUS are on a seperate drive so were unaffected.  During the rebuild process we thought it was time to update the server to 2008 R2 (from 2003 R2).

Have got the server running and installed the WSUS role, detached the DB form SQL Express 2008 R2 and attached the original.  Carried out the wsusutil.exe movecontent command with a -skipcopy switch pointing to the original content store.  All looked good until I saw the front page stating it is trying to download files for 6,436 updates at around 344,565 MB!!!!!!

Oops, I thought, something not right here.  The content store I have on disk is only 75GB but I am thinking that some vital step has been missed in the restoration process.  Either way is there a way to make WSUS reindex its local content store or something as I am unsure that downloading 344 gigabytes is a viable way forward!

EDIT: Never rains but it pours.  AM now getting a CLSID: FX {8b6499ed-0241-e032-6508-da4b1c879d7e} error could not create snap in.  think a reinstall of WSUS is in order.

Comment: indeed.  long old day so far.  thanks for pointing that out lol

Comment: I Have the some error when opening the MMC CLSID: FX {8b6499ed-0241-e032-6508-da4b1c879d7e} How did you fixed this?
Did you replaced the .net machine.config file?
source: [http://myworldofit.net/?p=773](http://myworldofit.net/?p=773) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the process for this was a touch convoluted but it worked in the end.

Had to do an in-place upgrade to repair the MMC

Then I was able to deploy WSUS and IIS again

Reattached the database and pointed WSUS to it

Moved the content store with -skipcopy

Spent an age fiddling with SQL permissions and NTFS permissions to the directory where the database was stored.

Ran the [WSUSMaintenance SQL script](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/6f8cde49-5c52-4abd-9820-f1d270ddea61)

It then only downloaded 80GB instead of 300+GB so could live with that.  Not perfect but got there in the end :)

Answer (score 0):

If you go under the options node towards the bottom, there are a couple that might be of benefit to you:

1. First I'd say make sure that you are only selecting the updates that you really need and not all of them. (under products and classifications).
2. You might also use the Server Cleanup Wizard there as well to do some cleanup, I'm unsure if it makes it reindex, but it cleans out some of the old, unused and depreciated updates I think.
3. Not sure where this setting is, but I would also think there was a setting to tell WSUS not to download any updates until you have approved it that way it doesn't take up space until you are actually ready to push it to workstations.

Hope that helps.